# Forward Fill NA

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a table with NaN.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['may','may', 'mary', 'james','james','john','paul', 'paul', 'joseph'],
       'email' : ['may@gmail.com','NaN','Mary@gmail.com','James@gmail.com','NaN','NaN','Paul@gmail.com','NaN','NaN']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

BEFORE

[image]

DESIRE OUTPUT

[image]

But, when I use `ffill`, I ended up with this which is incorrect. Is there a way I can use `ffill` but with conditions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `NaN` values are strings, with value `"NaN"`. So before you fillna, you'd have to convert those to actual null values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'name': ['may','may', 'mary', 'james','james','john','paul', 'paul', 'joseph'],
       'email' : ['may@gmail.com','NaN','Mary@gmail.com','James@gmail.com','NaN','NaN','Paul@gmail.com','NaN','NaN']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['email'] = df['email'].replace({'NaN':np.nan})
df['email'] = df.groupby('name')['email'].fillna(method='ffill')
df
```

```
     name            email
0     may    may@gmail.com
1     may    may@gmail.com
2    mary   Mary@gmail.com
3   james  James@gmail.com
4   james  James@gmail.com
5    john              NaN
6    paul   Paul@gmail.com
7    paul   Paul@gmail.com
8  joseph              NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
df.groupby('name').email.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = df.replace("NaN", np.nan)
df.update(df.groupby('name')['email'].ffill().fillna("NaN"))
df
```

---

```
    name    email
0   may     may@gmail.com
1   may     may@gmail.com
2   mary    Mary@gmail.com
3   james   James@gmail.com
4   james   James@gmail.com
5   john    NaN
6   paul    Paul@gmail.com
7   paul    Paul@gmail.com
8   joseph  NaN
```